# Blank.txt at the End of Transmission

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card, string

I'm using my HC-05 (Master) to receive strings from a sensor (Slave), each string is suppose to have 7 items divided by ',' like so "a,b,c,d,e,f,g". I also have to write these strings in a .txt file in the SD card, being that I receive the strings and save them in a string array to later be written to a file. For some reason I can't receive it and write it to a file simultaneously, it alters the string. So the best way would be an array but when i open the file it's blank and when I print it on screen it starts correctly then prints only the first char of what would be the string. I tried it with 80 strings and it works correctly, so I can only guess it would be insufficient memory, But wouldn't it still write to the file since there is something in the strings.

PS:I'm using Arduino Mega

```
#include <SD.h>

const int tam=480;
char aux;
File myFile;

void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Capture();
}

void openSD()
{
  SD.begin(4);
  if( SD.exists("test.txt") )
  {
    Serial.println("O arquivo de amostras sera removido");
    SD.remove("test.txt");  
      if( !SD.exists("test.txt") )
        Serial.println("Arquivo removido com sucesso!");
  }
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
}

void Capture()
{
  String test[tam];
  openSD();
  Serial.println("BEGIN");
  for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
  {
    test[i]="";
    do
    {
      while(!Serial1.available());
      aux=Serial1.read();
      test[i]+=aux;
      Serial.print(aux);
    }while(aux!='\n');
  }
  Serial.println("END");
  for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
    myFile.print(test[i]);
  myFile.close();
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Your strings should _barely_ fit in memory if each item is a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Rules of sequential file is : **It's saved when its closed,** which mean if the file not closed properly, anything written before will not saved, and you'll get blank file.

so, if you get a blank file while you are sure that the data is received, the only possibility is your program doesn't reach

```
myFile.close();
```

one of the possibility is the received data not fit into your memory, so the '\n' is undetected.